# iPhone 5 displays black space in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios9

I am currently working on an iPhone 5 app in Xcode. The problem is when I run the app I get a black top space and black bottom space (iPhone 4 res).

How is it possible to show the app in an iPhone 5 res.

Comment: if you talk about "bars" you are actually referring to empty black space at the top and bottom, right? not actual navigation bar (top) or tab bar (bottom)!?

Comment: yes i mean the empty black spaces i will change the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `Default-568h@2x.png` launch screen image. It should be 640 × 1136 px

Comment: how to add the image ??

Comment: @Jeroen Just drag and drop it into your Xcode project or add it to your xcassets file.